# NSURLSession vs Background Fetch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

Ok, so I was looking at the SimpleBackgroundFetch example project, and it uses the following in the App Delegate:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:someTimeInSeconds];
//^this code is in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions


-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  //do something + call completionHandler depending on new data / no data / fail
}
```

So, basically I assume, that I call my app's server here, to get some data.

But then I saw the NSURLSession [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/Introduction/Introduction.html), and it had methods like these

```
– downloadTaskWithURL:
```

and it said the following:

> This API provides a rich set of delegate methods for supporting
>   authentication and gives your app the ability to perform background
>   downloads when your app is not running or, in iOS, while your app is
>   suspended.

**So what's the difference between these two APIs? And what should I use if I want to download some data from my app's server every now and again?**

I just wasn't sure about the difference between the two, so I just thought I should get my doubts clarified here. **Go StackOverflow!**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**These are completely different things.**

- **Background Fetch**: System launches your app at some time (heuristics) and your job is to **start** downloading new content for user.
- **NSURLSession**: Replacement for *NSURLConnection*, that allows the downloads to **continue** after the app is suspended.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the clarification, sometimes the docs can be cumbersome. The "start/continue" phrasing helped me understand it. So I guess I should just use the App Delegate / Background Fetch style. Thanks!

Comment: Just one more thing. These two are not necessary used in conjuction. If the _content for user_ needs small data request, like some feed updates, then it's not good to use _background mode_ for NSURLSession. Background mode is mainly for downloading files and such downloads may be paused by system when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. I appreciate it. It's just getting some JSON from the server so, background fetch is fine, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

The application delegate is for storing the completion handler so you can call it when your download is finished.

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSString *)identifier completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"Handle events for background url session");

    self.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler = completionHandler;
}
```

and call the handler

```
- (void)URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSURLSession *)session {
    WebAppDelegate *appDelegate = (WebAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler) {
        void (^completionHandler)() = appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler;
        appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler = nil;

        completionHandler();
    }
    NSLog(@"All tasks are finished");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**NSURLSession**:Allows to uploading and downloading in the background mode and suspend mode of application

**Background Fetch**:Happens according to volume of the data and duration of previous data transferring process.Only last for 30s.

Answer (score 0):

So you confirm a background URLSession endowed with a delegate should be called, while a normal dataTask with block may not be?